# How i get the current URL segment as constants

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

it's possible to save the current URL in constants for used this in setup?

URL Example: **example.com/de/site1** 
I need the URL segment: **"/de/site2"**

**Part of my constants:**

```
#--------------------------------------------------
# Site Config
siteConfig {
  homePid = 2
  footerNaviPid = 4
  currentURL =
}
```

In the setup i build a onPager navi and need the currentURL segment there.

Part of my setup

```
#---------------------
# Make Sections for OnePager
lib.sectionContentNavi = HMENU
lib.sectionContentNavi {
  wrap = |
  #entryLevel = 1
  special = directory
  special.value = 2
  #excludeUidList  = 25 
  
  entryLevel = 1
    
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
    expAll = 1
    noBlur = 1
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

   NO {
    wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    linkWrap =|
   }

   ACT = 1
   ACT {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li class="act">|</li>
       linkWrap =|
   }
   }     
 
  2 = TMENU
  2 {
    expAll = 1
    noBlur = 1
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
 
    NO = 1
    NO {
      doNotLinkIt = 1
      linkWrap = <li>|</li>
      stdWrap >
      stdWrap {
        wrap = <a href="{$siteConfig.aktuelleURL}#s{field:uid}">|</a>
        insertData = 1
        cObject = TEXT
        cObject {
          field = nav_title // title          
        }
      }
    }
    ACT = 1
    ACT {
       wrapItemAndSub = <li class="act">|</li>
       linkWrap =|
    }
  }
}
```

A tip from you make me happy :-)

Greets Deukaei

Comment: What are you going to achieve exactly? Where do you need the current url?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have updated my Question :-)

In the setup i build onPager navi and need the currentURL segment there

Comment: `forceAbsoluteUrl` of typolink is your friend: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Typolink.html#forceabsoluteurl

Comment: Julian, thank you for your tip, can you help me please, how i implements in my setup?
i need this in this line:  wrap = <a href="{$siteConfig.aktuelleURL}#s{field:uid}">|</a>

Comment: I would recommend to use a MenuProcessor. There you can handle the HTML and links much more easier than in TypoScript. Look at: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing.html#menuprocessor

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your rcommend. Have you nevertheless a tip for me how i get the currentURL in the constants, for use this in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

you cant get variable data in your typoscript constants.

you can use variables in your setup (something like GET, POST or ENV).
for easier (or multiple) usage you can store these values in register variables.

But you should not build `a`-tags in typoscript or fluid on your own.
Try to use `typolink` or `f:link` viewhelpers.

in this way you never need to access the current URL as you only link to a page uid (and maybe action paramters and record parameters) and TYPO3 resolves it to the correct path segments.